# How to delete 2 rows at a time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to delete two rows at a time using JavaScript even though only for first row radio button exist?

Something like this:

- 1st row: (radiobutton) some textfield
- 2nd row: text field

On click of delete button, both the row should get deleted but the code which I have written is deleting only 1st row not 2nd one.

JavaScript code looks something like this:

```
function deleteReserveDetails() {
    if (!document.forms[0].reserveRadiobutton) {
        return;
    } else {
        var hidValue = parseInt(document.forms[0].Hd1Value.value);
        var reserveRows = document.getElementById('reserveTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var headerNo = 1;
        var radio = eval("document.forms[0].reserveRadiobutton");
        if (radio.length == undefined) {
            if (radio.checked) {
                var hidValue1 = parseInt(document.forms[0].Hd1Value.value) - 1;
                document.forms[0].Hd1Value.value = hidValue1;
                document.getElementById('reserveTable').deleteRow(headerNo);
            }
            return;
        }
        var k = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++) {
            if (radio[j].checked) {
                if (j == hidValue - 1) {
                    var hidValue2 = parseInt(document.forms[0].Hd1Value.value) - 1;
                    document.forms[0].Hd1Value.value = hidValue2;
                }
                document.getElementById('reserveTable').deleteRow(j + headerNo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Could you please show me how to modify it to delete 2 rows at a time?

Comment: You're not using any jQuery code in your example. Did you mean to tag it with that?

Comment: Yea, just post your HTML code. It is not clear if you refer to a table rows or maybe some divs that act like rows.